# How to create horizontal list like original android menu?

Tags: android

I have list of some informations and I want to show each item on screen. And There should be dots under or over the screen that shows which order I am. You can imagine original android menu

[image]

How can I create list like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `ViewPager` with `PageTitleStrip`. Or add your own custom view at top and show which index `ViewPager` is on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom class to achieve your requirements:

**HorizontalPagerWithPageControl**

> ```
>    /**
>     * A view group that allows users to switch between multiple screens (layouts)
>      * in the same way as the Android home screen (Launcher application).     
>      * You can add and remove views using the normal methods
>     * {@link ViewGroup#addView(View)}, {@link ViewGroup#removeView(View)} etc. You
>     * may want to listen for updates by calling      
>     * {@link HorizontalPagerWithPageControl#setOnScreenSwitchListener(OnScreenSwitchListener)}
>     * in order to perform operations once a new screen has been selected.
>     * 
>     * Modifications from original version (ysamlan): Animate argument in
>     * setCurrentScreen and duration in snapToScreen; onInterceptTouchEvent handling
>     * to support nesting a vertical Scrollview inside the RealViewSwitcher;
>     * allowing snapping to a view even during an ongoing scroll; snap to next/prev
>     * view on 25% scroll change; density-independent swipe sensitivity;
>     * width-independent pager animation durations on scrolling to properly handle
>       * large screens without excessively long animations.
>     * 
>     * Modifications from the version of ysamlan: Added page control to the bottom
>     * of this view.
>     * 
>     * Other modifications: (aveyD) Handle orientation changes properly and fully
>     * snap to the right position.
>     * 
>     * @author Marc Reichelt, <a
>     *         href="http://www.marcreichelt.de/">http://www.marcreichelt.de/</a>
>     * @version 0.1.0
>     */
>    public final class HorizontalPagerWithPageControl extends ViewGroup {
> /*
>  * How long to animate between screens when programmatically setting with
>  * setCurrentScreen using the animate parameter
>  */
> private static final int ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS = 500;
> // What fraction (1/x) of the screen the user must swipe to indicate a page
> // change
> private static final int FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE = 4;
> private static final int INVALID_SCREEN = -1;
> /*
>  * Velocity of a swipe (in density-independent pixels per second) to force a
>  * swipe to the next/previous screen. Adjusted into
>  * mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity on init.
>  */
> private static final int SNAP_VELOCITY_DIP_PER_SECOND = 600;
> // Argument to getVelocity for units to give pixels per second (1 = pixels
> // per millisecond).
> private static final int VELOCITY_UNIT_PIXELS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
> private static final int TOUCH_STATE_REST = 0;
> private static final int TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING = 1;
> private static final int TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING = -1;
> private int m_currentScreen;
> private int m_densityAdjustedSnapVelocity;
> private boolean m_firstLayout = true;
> private float m_lastMotionX;
> private float m_lastMotionY;
> private OnScreenSwitchListener m_onScreenSwitchListener;
> private int m_maximumVelocity;
> private int m_nextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;
> private Scroller m_scroller;
> private int m_touchSlop;
> private int m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
> private VelocityTracker m_velocityTracker;
> private int m_lastSeenLayoutWidth = -1;
> // Active and inactive draw
> private Drawable m_activeDrawable;
> private Drawable m_inactiveDrawable;
> // The size for the drawables
> private float m_indicatorSize;
> // The screen scale to get px to dip
> private static float SCALE;
> /**
>  * Simple constructor to use when creating a view from code.
>  * 
>  * @param p_context
>  *            The Context the view is running in, through which it can
>  *            access the current theme, resources, etc.
>  */
> public HorizontalPagerWithPageControl(final Context p_context) {
>     super(p_context);
>     init();
> }
> /**
>  * Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML. This is called
>  * when a view is being constructed from an XML file, supplying attributes
>  * that were specified in the XML file. This version uses a default style of
>  * 0, so the only attribute values applied are those in the Context's Theme
>  * and the given AttributeSet.
>  * 
>  * <p>
>  * The method onFinishInflate() will be called after all children have been
>  * added.
>  * 
>  * @param p_context
>  *            The Context the view is running in, through which it can
>  *            access the current theme, resources, etc.
>  * @param p_attrs
>  *            The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view.
>  * @see #View(Context, AttributeSet, int)
>  */
> public HorizontalPagerWithPageControl(final Context p_context,
>         final AttributeSet p_attrs) {
>     super(p_context, p_attrs);
>     init();
> }
> /**
>  * Sets up the scroller and touch/fling sensitivity parameters for the
>  * pager.
>  */
> private void init() {
>     m_scroller = new Scroller(getContext());
>     // get the screen density
>     SCALE = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
>     // set the indicator size resolution independent
>     m_indicatorSize = (7 * SCALE);
>     // Calculate the density-dependent snap velocity in pixels
>     DisplayMetrics m_displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
>     ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
>             .getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(m_displayMetrics);
>     m_densityAdjustedSnapVelocity = (int) (m_displayMetrics.density * SNAP_VELOCITY_DIP_PER_SECOND);
>     final ViewConfiguration m_configuration = ViewConfiguration
>             .get(getContext());
>     m_touchSlop = m_configuration.getScaledTouchSlop();
>     m_maximumVelocity = m_configuration.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
>     // draw the shapes
>     makeShapes();
> }
> @Override
> protected void onMeasure(final int p_widthMeasureSpec,
>         final int p_heightMeasureSpec) {
>     super.onMeasure(p_widthMeasureSpec, p_heightMeasureSpec);
>     final int m_width = MeasureSpec.getSize(p_widthMeasureSpec);
>     final int m_widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(p_widthMeasureSpec);
>     if (m_widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
>         throw new IllegalStateException(
>                 "ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.");
>     }
>     final int m_heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(p_heightMeasureSpec);
>     if (m_heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
>         throw new IllegalStateException(
>                 "ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.");
>     }
>     // The children are given the same width and height as the workspace
>     final int m_count = getChildCount();
>     for (int m_i = 0; m_i < m_count; m_i++) {
>         getChildAt(m_i).measure(p_widthMeasureSpec, p_heightMeasureSpec);
>     }
>     if (m_firstLayout) {
>         scrollTo(m_currentScreen * m_width, 0);
>         m_firstLayout = false;
>     }
>     else if (m_width != m_lastSeenLayoutWidth) { // Width has changed
>         /*
>          * Recalculate the width and scroll to the right position to be sure
>          * we're in the right place in the event that we had a rotation that
>          * didn't result in an activity restart (code by aveyD). Without
>          * this you can end up between two pages after a rotation.
>          */
>         Display m_display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(
>                 Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
>         int m_displayWidth = m_display.getWidth();
>         m_nextScreen = Math.max(0,
>                 Math.min(getCurrentScreen(), getChildCount() - 1));
>         final int m_newX = m_nextScreen * m_displayWidth;
>         final int m_delta = m_newX - getScrollX();
>         m_scroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, m_delta, 0, 0);
>     }
>     m_lastSeenLayoutWidth = m_width;
> }
> @Override
> protected void onLayout(final boolean p_changed, final int p_l,
>         final int p_t, final int p_r, final int p_b) {
>     int m_childLeft = 0;
>     final int m_count = getChildCount();
>     for (int m_i = 0; m_i < m_count; m_i++) {
>         final View m_child = getChildAt(m_i);
>         if (m_child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
>             final int m_childWidth = m_child.getMeasuredWidth();
>             m_child.layout(m_childLeft, 0, m_childLeft + m_childWidth,
>                     m_child.getMeasuredHeight());
>             m_childLeft += m_childWidth;
>         }
>     }
> }
> @Override
> public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent p_ev) {
>     /*
>      * By Yoni Samlan: Modified onInterceptTouchEvent based on standard
>      * ScrollView's onIntercept. The logic is designed to support a nested
>      * vertically scrolling view inside this one; once a scroll registers
>      * for X-wise scrolling, handle it in this view and don't let the
>      * children, but once a scroll registers for y-wise scrolling, let the
>      * children handle it exclusively.
>      */
>     final int m_action = p_ev.getAction();
>     boolean m_intercept = false;
>     switch (m_action) {
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
>         /*
>          * If we're in a horizontal scroll event, take it (intercept further
>          * events). But if we're mid-vertical-scroll, don't even try; let
>          * the children deal with it. If we haven't found a scroll event
>          * yet, check for one.
>          */
>         if (m_touchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
>             /*
>              * We've already started a horizontal scroll; set intercept to
>              * true so we can take the remainder of all touch events in
>              * onTouchEvent.
>              */
>             m_intercept = true;
>         } else if (m_touchState == TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING) {
>             // Let children handle the events for the duration of the scroll
>             // event.
>             m_intercept = false;
>         } else { // We haven't picked up a scroll event yet; check for one.
>             /*
>              * If we detected a horizontal scroll event, start stealing
>              * touch events (mark as scrolling). Otherwise, see if we had a
>              * vertical scroll event -- if so, let the children handle it
>              * and don't look to intercept again until the motion is done.
>              */
>             final float m_x = p_ev.getX();
>             final int m_xDiff = (int) Math.abs(m_x - m_lastMotionX);
>             boolean m_xMoved = m_xDiff > m_touchSlop;
>             if (m_xMoved) {
>                 // Scroll if the user moved far enough along the X axis
>                 m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
>                 m_lastMotionX = m_x;
>             }
>             final float m_y = p_ev.getY();
>             final int m_yDiff = (int) Math.abs(m_y - m_lastMotionY);
>             boolean m_yMoved = m_yDiff > m_touchSlop;
>             if (m_yMoved) {
>                 m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING;
>             }
>         }
>         break;
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
>         // Release the drag.
>         m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
>         break;
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
>         /*
>          * No motion yet, but register the coordinates so we can check for
>          * intercept at the next MOVE event.
>          */
>         m_lastMotionY = p_ev.getY();
>         m_lastMotionX = p_ev.getX();
>         break;
>     default:
>         break;
>     }
>     return m_intercept;
> }
> @Override
> public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent p_ev) {
>     if (m_velocityTracker == null) {
>         m_velocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
>     }
>     m_velocityTracker.addMovement(p_ev);
>     final int m_action = p_ev.getAction();
>     final float m_x = p_ev.getX();
>     switch (m_action) {
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
>         /*
>          * If being flinged and user touches, stop the fling. isFinished
>          * will be false if being flinged.
>          */
>         if (!m_scroller.isFinished()) {
>             m_scroller.abortAnimation();
>         }
>         // Remember where the motion event started
>         m_lastMotionX = m_x;
>         if (m_scroller.isFinished()) {
>             m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
>         } else {
>             m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
>         }
>         break;
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
>         final int m_xDiff = (int) Math.abs(m_x - m_lastMotionX);
>         boolean m_xMoved = m_xDiff > m_touchSlop;
>         if (m_xMoved) {
>             // Scroll if the user moved far enough along the X axis
>             m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
>         }
>         if (m_touchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
>             // Scroll to follow the motion event
>             final int m_deltaX = (int) (m_lastMotionX - m_x);
>             m_lastMotionX = m_x;
>             final int m_scrollX = getScrollX();
>             if (m_deltaX < 0) {
>                 if (m_scrollX > 0) {
>                     scrollBy(Math.max(-m_scrollX, m_deltaX), 0);
>                 }
>             } else if (m_deltaX > 0) {
>                 final int m_availableToScroll = getChildAt(
>                         getChildCount() - 1).getRight()
>                         - m_scrollX - getWidth();
>                 if (m_availableToScroll > 0) {
>                     scrollBy(Math.min(m_availableToScroll, m_deltaX), 0);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         break;
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
>         if (m_touchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
>             final VelocityTracker m_velocityTrack = m_velocityTracker;
>             m_velocityTrack.computeCurrentVelocity(
>                     VELOCITY_UNIT_PIXELS_PER_SECOND, m_maximumVelocity);
>             int m_velocityX = (int) m_velocityTrack.getXVelocity();
>             if (m_velocityX > m_densityAdjustedSnapVelocity
>                     && m_currentScreen > 0) {
>                 // Fling hard enough to move left
>                 snapToScreen(m_currentScreen - 1);
>             } else if (m_velocityX < -m_densityAdjustedSnapVelocity
>                     && m_currentScreen < getChildCount() - 1) {
>                 // Fling hard enough to move right
>                 snapToScreen(m_currentScreen + 1);
>             } else {
>                 snapToDestination();
>             }
>             if (m_velocityTracker != null) {
>                 m_velocityTracker.recycle();
>                 m_velocityTracker = null;
>             }
>         }
>         m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
>         break;
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
>         m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
>         break;
>     default:
>         break;
>     }
>     return true;
> }
> @Override
> public void computeScroll() {
>     if (m_scroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
>         scrollTo(m_scroller.getCurrX(), m_scroller.getCurrY());
>         postInvalidate();
>     } else if (m_nextScreen != INVALID_SCREEN) {
>         m_currentScreen = Math.max(0,
>                 Math.min(m_nextScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
>         // Notify observer about screen change
>         if (m_onScreenSwitchListener != null) {
>             m_onScreenSwitchListener.onScreenSwitched(m_currentScreen);
>         }
>         m_nextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;
>     }
> }
> /**
>  * Returns the index of the currently displayed screen.
>  * 
>  * @return The index of the currently displayed screen.
>  */
> public int getCurrentScreen() {
>     return m_currentScreen;
> }
> /**
>  * Sets the current screen.
>  * 
>  * @param p_currentScreen
>  *            The new screen.
>  * @param p_animate
>  *            True to smoothly scroll to the screen, false to snap instantly
>  */
> public void setCurrentScreen(final int p_currentScreen,
>         final boolean p_animate) {
>     m_currentScreen = Math.max(0,
>             Math.min(p_currentScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
>     if (p_animate) {
>         snapToScreen(p_currentScreen, ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS);
>     } else {
>         scrollTo(m_currentScreen * getWidth(), 0);
>     }
>     invalidate();
> }
> /**
>  * Sets the {@link OnScreenSwitchListener}.
>  * 
>  * @param onScreenSwitchListener
>  *            The listener for switch events.
>  */
> public void setOnScreenSwitchListener(
>         final OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener) {
>     m_onScreenSwitchListener = onScreenSwitchListener;
> }
> /**
>  * Snaps to the screen we think the user wants (the current screen for very
>  * small movements; the next/prev screen for bigger movements).
>  */
> private void snapToDestination() {
>     final int m_screenWidth = getWidth();
>     int m_scrollX = getScrollX();
>     int m_whichScreen = m_currentScreen;
>     int m_deltaX = m_scrollX - (m_screenWidth * m_currentScreen);
>     // Check if they want to go to the prev. screen
>     if ((m_deltaX < 0)
>             && m_currentScreen != 0
>             && ((m_screenWidth / FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE) < -m_deltaX)) {
>         m_whichScreen--;
>         // Check if they want to go to the next screen
>     } else if ((m_deltaX > 0)
>             && (m_currentScreen + 1 != getChildCount())
>             && ((m_screenWidth / FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE) < m_deltaX)) {
>         m_whichScreen++;
>     }
>     snapToScreen(m_whichScreen);
> }
> /**
>  * Snap to a specific screen, animating automatically for a duration
>  * proportional to the distance left to scroll.
>  * 
>  * @param p_whichScreen
>  *            Screen to snap to
>  */
> private void snapToScreen(final int p_whichScreen) {
>     snapToScreen(p_whichScreen, -1);
> }
> /**
>  * Snaps to a specific screen, animating for a specific amount of time to
>  * get there.
>  * 
>  * @param p_whichScreen
>  *            Screen to snap to
>  * @param p_duration
>  *            -1 to automatically time it based on scroll distance; a
>  *            positive number to make the scroll take an exact duration.
>  */
> private void snapToScreen(final int p_whichScreen, final int p_duration) {
>     /*
>      * Modified by Yoni Samlan: Allow new snapping even during an ongoing
>      * scroll animation. This is intended to make HorizontalPager work as
>      * expected when used in conjunction with a RadioGroup used as "tabbed"
>      * controls. Also, make the animation take a percentage of our normal
>      * animation time, depending how far they've already scrolled.
>      */
>     m_nextScreen = Math
>             .max(0, Math.min(p_whichScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
>     final int m_newX = m_nextScreen * getWidth();
>     final int m_delta = m_newX - getScrollX();
>     if (p_duration < 0) {
>         // E.g. if they've scrolled 80% of the way, only animation for 20%
>         // of the duration
>         m_scroller
>                 .startScroll(
>                         getScrollX(),
>                         0,
>                         m_delta,
>                         0,
>                         (int) (Math.abs(m_delta) / (float) getWidth() * ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS));
>     } else {
>         m_scroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, m_delta, 0, p_duration);
>     }
>     // sets the drawables when the user swipes
>     setActiveInactiveDrawables(p_whichScreen);
>     // redraw screen
>     invalidate();
> }
> /**
>  * Allways called when the user swipes to another view. Gets the current
>  * view an sets the active drawable / shape to the curretn view. (in the
>  * page control)
>  */
> public void setActiveInactiveDrawables(int p_whichScreen) {
>     // Getting the Linear Layout where the page control drawables are inside
>     LinearLayout m_linLayout = (LinearLayout) ((ViewGroup) this.getParent())
>             .getChildAt(((LinearLayout) this.getParent()).getChildCount() - 1);
>     // get every imageview and set the one of the current screen to active
>     for (int m_i = 0; m_i < this.getChildCount(); m_i++) {
>         ImageView m_imgView = (ImageView) m_linLayout.getChildAt(m_i);
>         if (m_i == p_whichScreen) {
>             m_imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(m_activeDrawable);
>         } else {
>             m_imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(m_inactiveDrawable);
>         }
>     }
> }
> /**
>  * Listener for the event that the HorizontalPager switches to a new view.
>  */
> public static interface OnScreenSwitchListener {
>     /**
>      * Notifies listeners about the new screen. Runs after the animation
>      * completed.
>      * 
>      * @param screen
>      *            The new screen index.
>      */
>     void onScreenSwitched(int screen);
> }
> /**
>  * Builds the active and inactive shapes / drawables for the page control
>  */
> private void makeShapes() {
>     m_activeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
>     m_inactiveDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
>     m_activeDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) m_indicatorSize,
>             (int) m_indicatorSize);
>     m_inactiveDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) m_indicatorSize,
>             (int) m_indicatorSize);
>     int m_i[] = new int[2];
>     m_i[0] = android.R.attr.textColorSecondary;
>     m_i[1] = android.R.attr.textColorSecondaryInverse;
>     TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(m_i);
>     Shape m_s1 = new OvalShape();
>     m_s1.resize(m_indicatorSize, m_indicatorSize);
>     Shape m_s2 = new OvalShape();
>     m_s2.resize(m_indicatorSize, m_indicatorSize);
>     ((ShapeDrawable) m_activeDrawable).getPaint().setColor(
>             a.getColor(0, Color.DKGRAY));
>     ((ShapeDrawable) m_inactiveDrawable).getPaint().setColor(
>             a.getColor(1, Color.LTGRAY));
>     ((ShapeDrawable) m_activeDrawable).setShape(m_s1);
>     ((ShapeDrawable) m_inactiveDrawable).setShape(m_s2);
> }
> /**
>  * Called by the Activity when all Views are added to the horizontal pager
>  * to
>  */
> public void addPagerControl() {
>     ViewGroup m_view = (ViewGroup) this.getParent();
>     m_view.addView(initPageControl());
> }
> private LinearLayout initPageControl() {
>     LinearLayout m_linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
>     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
>             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
>             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2f);
>     m_linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
>     m_linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
>     m_linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
>             | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
>     m_linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
>     return setPageCount(this.getChildCount(), m_linearLayout);
> }
> /**
>  * Initializes the page control layout at be bottom of the news view. Draws
>  * all page control shapes an set the active shape to the first view
>  * 
>  * @param p_pageCount
>  *            the cout of the pages the user can swipe to
>  * @param p_linearLayout2
>  *            the page control linearlayout
>  * @return the given layout filled with the page control shapes
>  */
> private LinearLayout setPageCount(int p_pageCount,
>         LinearLayout p_linearLayout2) {
>     for (int m_i = 0; m_i < p_pageCount; m_i++) {
>         final ImageView m_imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
>         LinearLayout.LayoutParams m_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
>                 (int) m_indicatorSize, (int) m_indicatorSize);
>         m_params.setMargins((int) m_indicatorSize / 2,
>                 (int) m_indicatorSize, (int) m_indicatorSize / 2,
>                 (int) m_indicatorSize);
>         m_imageView.setLayoutParams(m_params);
>         m_imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(m_inactiveDrawable);
>         if (m_i == 0) {
>             m_imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(m_activeDrawable);
>         }
>         p_linearLayout2.addView(m_imageView);
>     }
>     return p_linearLayout2;
> }
>    }
> ```

Use this above calss as below :

> ```
>  private HorizontalPagerWithPageControl m_pager;
> @Override
> public void onCreate(final Bundle p_savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(p_savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.horizontal_pager_with_page_control);
>     m_pager = (HorizontalPagerWithPageControl) findViewById(R.id.hphorizontal_pager);
>     /*
>      * You can add more views to the horizontal pager here with
>      * mPager.addChild() or in xml. When every view is in the horizontal
>      * pager just call addPagerControl() on the horzizontal pager.
>      */
>     m_pager.addPagerControl();
> }
> ```

Layout file:

> ```
>   <com.wli.horizontalpager.withpagecontrol.HorizontalPagerWithPageControl
>     android:id="@+id/hphorizontal_pager"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_weight="0.1"
>     android:background="#00000000">
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>             android:text="@string/lipsum"
>             android:textSize="24sp"
>             android:textColor="#000"
>             android:textStyle="bold"
>             android:background="#f00" />
>     <ScrollView
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>             android:text="@string/lipsum"
>             android:textSize="24sp"
>             android:textColor="#000"
>             android:textStyle="bold"
>             android:background="#0f0" />
>     </ScrollView>
>        </com.wli.horizontalpager.withpagecontrol.HorizontalPagerWithPageControl>
> ```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.